# extended select in SQL

Tags: sql

Not really sure how to phrase the question, however looking to do the following for the first time but struggling with it. Unfortunately not sure on the exact DB engine running beneath with the high likelihood of it being of IBM origin.

Doing a simplistic data example:

```
TRANSACTIONS
Trans_ID   Product_code
    1        A1
    1        B2
    1        A9
    2        B3
    2        B4
    3        A1
    3        A9
    3        A8
    4        C2
    5        D3
    5        A1
```

So, I am able to use a specific Product Code (i.e. A1) to identify the Transaction ID, however, I would need to get ALL rows in the result containing the Transaction ID where the matching Product code is found.

Meaning that I can use Product Code A1 as a key, however I would need to receive all 3 rows with TransID 1, then 3 rows with TransID 3 etc.

So, the results should display this:

```
Trans_ID    Product_code
   1        A1
   1        B2
   1        A9
   3        A1
   3        A9
   3        A8
   5        D3
   5        A1
```

Comment: `select * from X where trans_id in (select trans_id from X where product_code = 'A1')`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways how to tackle such query. The first one mentioned in comments:

```
select *
from X
where trans_id in (select trans_id from X where product_code = 'A1')
```

The second one using exists operator:

```
select *
from X x1
where exists (select *
              from X x2
              where product_code = 'A1' and x1.trans_id = x2.trans_id
             )
```

Next one using a self-join:

```
select x1.trans_id, x1.product_code 
from X x1 join
     X x2
     on x1.trans_id = x2.trans_id
where x2.product_code = 'A1'
```

I believe that I'm missing some other simple solutions (for example using ANY), however, these are the most straight forward ones.